# Dependency Injection: how do I integrate values received from method parameters into dependencies that I want to resolve as constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

Please bear with me - this is a complicated question, and I've simplified it as much as I am able. (I'm using ASP.NET web API and AutoFac and omitted a bunch of configuration for brevity.)

My goal is to maximize the extent to which dependency-injection is handled by a DI framework, in a situation where not all dependencies of some objects can be known until runtime.

Our players are:

- a CONTROLLER class that accepts web requests, the entry point to the app - the input includes `repoName`
- a REPOSITORY RESOLVER class, a factory that resolves a `repoName` into a specific REPOSITORY. Here's its implementation:

```
    public class RepositoryResolver : IRepositoryResolver
    {
        public IRepository Resolve(string repoName)
        {
            return new Repository(new Input { RepoName = repoName });
        }
    }
```

- a REPOSITORY class (representing a DB or whatever). Here's its implementation:

```
    public class Repository : IRepository
    {
        private readonly Input input; // proxy for connection string or other identifying information
    
        public Repository (Input input)
        {
            this.input = input;
        }

        public string[] Get()
        {
            return new[] { "I", "am", "a", input.RepoName };
        }
    }
```

- a BUSINESS LOGIC class that computes a result. The BUSINESS LOGIC class depends on a single repository; it knows nothing of multiple repositories or the repository resolver because it's not concerned with them. Here's its implementation:

```
    public class BusinessLogic : IBusinessLogic
    {
        private readonly IRepository repository;

        public BusinessLogic(IRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public string[] Compute()
        {
            return repository.Get();
        }
    }
```

Procedurally, what I'm trying to accomplish (in this stripped-down toy example) is very straightforward. Here's an example implementation of the controller:

**Proposed Answer #1 - Pure DI (no container)**

```
public class PureDIController : ApiController
{
    public ProceduralValuesController() { }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string repoName)
    {
        IRepositoryResolver repoSource = new RepositoryResolver();
        IRepository repo = repoSource.Resolve(repoName);
        IBusinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogic(repo);
        return businessLogic.Compute();
    }
}
```

...and this works, but obviously I'm not using a DI container here. When using pure DI like this, changes to one player tend to have ripple effects beyond its immediate collaborators and potentially through many layers (not represented here); I feel like moving this composition logic into a DI container will reduce a lot of that type of refactoring. That's the value proposition of this question.

However, when I try to rewrite this class using dependency-injection, I encounter a problem: the BUSINESS LOGIC depends on the REPOSITORY, so it cannot be resolved by a pre-created DI container. Hence, I cannot resolve the hand-waving comment here:

```
public class DIValuesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRepositoryResolver repoSource;
    private readonly IBusinessLogic businessLogic;

    public DIValuesController(
        IRepositoryResolver repoSource,
        IBusinessLogic businessLogic)
    {
        this.repoSource = repoSource;
        this.businessLogic = businessLogic;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string repoName)
    {
        var repo = repoSource.Resolve(repoName);
        /* ...handwaving to integrate repo into businessLogic... */
        return businessLogic.Compute();
    }
}
```

...because `IBusinessLogic` cannot be resolved at the time the controller is instantiated.

I've developed several possible solutions, and I will add them as potential answers. However, I don't like any of them, hence the post. ¯_(ツ)_/¯ **Please surprise me with something I haven't thought of yet!**

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility - pass IBusinessLogic to Controller not as an instance, but as a factory (i.e. Func<string, IBusinessLogic>) and in Methode Compute Fall factory with repoName.
See, for example:
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html

Comment: This is an interesting feature, but I can't find a way to implement it that doesn't lead to one or more of the problems with the already-posted solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #2 - Pass parameters as necessary**

This solution abandons the original premise that we can fruitfully convert a method parameter into a constructor parameter. Instead, it assumes that the repoName (or some equivalent differentiator) will need to be passed into any function that requires that information. Here's one possible example implementation of the controller (note that BusinessLogic now requires an additional parameter):

```
public class ParameterPassingController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IBusinessLogic businessLogic;

    public ParameterPassingController(
        IBusinessLogic businessLogic)
    {
        this.businessLogic = businessLogic;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string repoName)
    {
        return businessLogic.Compute(repoName);
    }
}
```

And here's the new implementation of `BusinessLogic`:

```
public class BusinessLogic : IBusinessLogic
{
    private readonly IRepositoryResolver repositoryResolver;

    public BusinessLogic(IRepository repositoryResolver)
    {
        this.repositoryResolver = repositoryResolver;
    }

    public string[] Compute(string repoName)
    {
        var repo = repositoryResolver.Resolve(repoName);
        return repo.Get();
    }
}
```

This solution feels very awkward because it modifies the BusinessLogic class to depend on a less direct object than it did before. A class's dependencies should be determined by the class, not by the needs of the caller. The BusinessLogic class was better the way it was before, and any solution that causes us to make it more complicated is probably not a good one.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer #3 - Introduce additional resolvers**

This solution adds a BUSINESS LOGIC RESOLVER, using the same pattern as the REPOSITORY RESOLVER. (Factory pattern?)

```
public class BusinessLogicResolverController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRepositoryResolver repoSource;
    private readonly IBusinessLogicResolver businessLogicSource;

    public BusinessLogicResolverController(
        IRepositoryResolver repoSource,
        IBusinessLogicResolver businessLogicSource)
    {
        this.repoSource = repoSource;
        this.businessLogicSource = businessLogicSource;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string repoName)
    {
        var repo = repoSource.Resolve(repoName);
        var businessLogic = businessLogicSource.Resolve(repo);
        return businessLogic.Compute();
    }
}
```

The thing I don't like about this is that if there are many classes that depend on a single IRepository (and in my non-trivial example, there are many), I need to create a Resolver for each of them. That also complicates other things that DI containers can help with like decorator application and stuff.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer #4 - Introduce temporal coupling**

This solution replaces the registered implementation of IRepository with a class that also implements IRepositoryManager, allowing it to be pointed at the appropriate repo at runtime. Here's what the controller looks like now:

```
public class TemporallyCoupledController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRepositoryManager repoManager;
    private readonly IBusinessLogic businessLogic;

    public TemporallyCoupledController(
        IRepositoryManager repoManager,
        IBusinessLogic businessLogic)
    {
        this.repoManager = repoManager;
        this.businessLogic = businessLogic;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string repoName)
    {
        repoManager.Set(repoName);
        return businessLogic.Compute();
    }
}
```

...and here's the implementation of IRepositoryManager:

```
public class RepositoryManager : IRepositoryManager, IRepository
{
    private readonly IRepositoryResolver resolver;
    private IRepository repo = null;

    public RepositoryManager(IRepositoryResolver resolver)
    {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    void IRepositoryManager.Set(string repoName)
    {
        this.repo = resolver.Resolve(repoName);
    }

    string[] IRepository.Get()
    {
        if (repo == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(IRepositoryManager.Set)} must be called first.");
        else
            return repo.Get();
    }
}
```

This solution certainly allows the controller to stay small, but in my experience, temporal coupling almost always hurts more than it helps. Also, it's unclear that these two lines in the controller have anything to do with each other:

```
        repoManager.Set(repoName);
        return businessLogic.Compute();
```

...but obviously they do. So this is a pretty bad solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer #5 - Inject the parameter-based dependency inside the controller**

This solution makes the controller part of the composition root, rather than having it be resolved by dependency injection. (The line where the built container is retrieved could be done in other ways, but that's not the important part - the main idea is that we need to access its `BeginLifetimeScope` method directly after we have the input parameters.)

```
public class SelfAwareDIController : ApiController
{
    public SelfAwareDIController() { }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string repoName)
    {
        var container = (AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver;

        using (var scope = container.Container.BeginLifetimeScope(builder =>
            builder.RegisterInstance(new Input { RepoName = repoName }).AsSelf()))
        {
            var businessLogic = scope.Resolve<IBusinessLogic>();
            return businessLogic.Compute();
        }
    }
}
```

This solution avoids temporal coupling (since `businessLogic` cannot exist outside the lifetime scope where it can be resolved). It also allows us to remove the REPOSITORY RESOLVER; I was already uncomfortable with REPOSITORY RESOLVER because it's an expansion of the Composition Root that interferes with the DI container's centralized handling of object creation. A downside is that it moves some of the container-related code into the controller rather than keeping it all in the service configuration. (Again, in a non-trivial example there may be many controllers that need to implement similar logic.) It also prevents the controller itself from being instantiated by the DI container (which you can do with `AutoFac.WebApi2` package). Still, because it restricts the knowledge of this new context to the controller (and removes the necessity of having a factory class), this is probably the least objectionable of the solutions that I've identified.